# Can not run Insert query against mySQL database using Powershell, but can via the PHPMyAdmin UI

Tags: mysql, powershell

Im trying to run the following query against my mySQL database :

```
"INSERT INTO present (name) VALUES ('fred');"
```

I can run this query in the UI in PHPMyAdmin and it created the expected data, however, I can not run it from my PowerShell script. I can get data from the database using my PowerShell script, but can't seem to be able to create any. Any ideas ?

EDIT

Code I use to connect to database :

```
function ConnectToDatabase([string]$user, [string]$pass, [string]$MySQLHost, [string]$database) {

    Log "--------"
    Log "Connecting to database" 
    # Load MySQL .NET Connector Objects 
    [void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("MySql.Data") 

    # Open Connection 
    $connStr = "server=" + $MySQLHost + ";port=3306;uid=" + $user + ";pwd=" + $pass + ";database="+$database+";Pooling=FALSE" 
    try {
        $conn = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($connStr) 
        $conn.Open()
    } catch [System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException] {
        Log "Unable to connect to MySQL server, do you have the MySQL connector installed..?"
        Log $_
        #Exit
    } catch {
        Log "Unable to connect to MySQL server..."
        Log $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
        Log $_.Exception.Message
        #exit
    }
    Log "Connected to MySQL database : $MySQLHost\$database"
    Log "--------"

    return $conn 
}
```

Running the query

```
$conn = ConnectToDatabase $user $pass $MySQLHost $database
$query = "INSERT INTO present (name) VALUES ('fred');"
$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand $query, $conn
```

I also had this to GET data from the database but I thought it was redundant to the Insert of data

```
$dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($Command)
$dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$recordCount = $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet, "data")
return $dataSet.Tables[0]
```

Comment: Then please post your Powershell script ;) we can't help you without the code.

Comment: @Stony amended question. The credentials are fine, this queries work for getting data, but don't seem to be working for inserting

Comment: Any error messages? Are you using the same credentials in PhpMyAdmin and PowerShell?

Comment: no error messages in the console. I'm not sure how to catch the error messages ? When I write a query I know will not work, I don't get an errors, perhaps I need to catch them somehow ? And yes, same credentials in both

Comment: Can I mention, this was working at one point. And I can really remember the exact time it wasnt. But I remember resetting the auto increment to 1 and I think it was around a similar time it stopped working

Comment: The code you posted creates a `MySqlCommand` object, but doesn't actually execute the SQL statement.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i thought this creates and executes ? What is the correct way to execute ? (i will google in the meantime)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers i added some code to the question. I had that for getting data from the database, I thought it was redundant to the insert of data ?

Comment: [`$Command.ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers damn, I honestly thought it was all working within that one line. The $command.executenonquery() worked perfectly. Welcome to add it as an answer, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted creates a `MySqlCommand` object, but doesn't actually execute the SQL statement. Use the [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm) method for that:

```
$conn = ConnectToDatabase $user $pass $MySQLHost $database
$query = "INSERT INTO present (name) VALUES ('fred');"
$Command = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand $query, $conn
$Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```